# Size of my Cd-Rom (SATA)

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hard-drive, optical-drive, sata

I have a macbookPro 15'' mid 2009 and I want know which size is my cd-rom (SATA)because I have to buy [this "component"](http://www.amazon.it/LEICKE-Adattatore-universale-modelli-MacBook/dp/B00803HWGE/ref=sr_1_sc_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1389974038&sr=1-1-spell&keywords=adaptor%20cd%20ssd)

where can I find this information ?
My Cd-Rom is 9,5mm - SATA/SATA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your MacBook Pro has indeed a 9.5mm SATA SuperDrive](http://www.macpieces.com/lecteurs-optiques-macbook/panasonic-uj-868a-superdrive.html).

Comment: my MBP is 2,66 core 2 Duo 15'' mid 2009, is not in that list

Comment: Not a problem, all mid-2009 are the same.